# blank page after changed link - smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I wanted to help a friend on his website and he told me to change a link. he use smarty and the website is online

so i change this

```
<li class="first"><a href="{$path}reseau/le-reseau.html">Le réseau</a></li>
```

to absolute path.

Now, i have this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function reecrire_url() in /home/deflandrgb/www/includes/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_filter_handler.php on line 60
```

But I have not changed anything except link.

why I have this error?

Thanks

ps: I handed the old link but I still have the same error

EDIT : i find this function in Site_Smarty.class.php

```
class Site_Smarty extends Smarty{

public function Site_Smarty(){

    parent::__construct();

    //$this->caching = true;
    //$this->compile_check = true;


    $this->template_dir = root.'templates/';
    $this->compile_dir = root.'templates_c/';
    $this->config_dir = root.'includes/smarty/';
    $this->cache_dir = root.'cache/';

    //$this->debugging = true;

    $this->registerFilter('pre','reecrire_url');


    $this->assign('app_name', 'Guest Book');
    $this->assign('path', path);



}
```

}

Comment: The error says it all: reecrire_url() in line 60 is not defined. Maybe typos?

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible answer to this question with provided information.

Comment: I know but I do not know where to find this function

Comment: do a grep from commandline: `egrep -R /home/deflandrgb/www -ie 'function\s+reecrire_url'` or search it with a text editor with multi-file search capability

Comment: i edit my post with reecrire_url() function

Comment: and do you have defined the callback function "reecrire_url" ?

Comment: $this->assign('path', path); or $this->assign('path', $path); ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed to define the callback function `"reecrire_url"`

See docs:

> http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.filter.tpl